# Unfinished Video help?

Tags: osx-leopard

Does anyone have a clue how to edit an unfinished video? I had recored an hr long event for my kid but in between the camera hung. The format is a MOV. I downloaded the file on my Mac but it shows the dimension and duration of the video to be 'fetching', which I presume means it has no ending tags to indicated the length and end points of the video. I would love to recover at least part of the video if not all. Any ideas / help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ffmpeg might be able to fix the video, if you can get it installed on OS X

Answer (score 1):

This is a tool that can repair corrupted MOV files which are " truncated, broken, corrupt or damaged".

http://grauonline.de/cmsimple2_6/en/?Solutions:HD_Video_Repair_Utility

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Video_Repair_Tool

They have a free demo, but it has limitations.  You can try the demo and see if it fixes your file, but you may have to buy the paid version to fix the whole file.